# Excel to access

Tags: ms-access

With respect to below macro. Which VB Reference setting I have to do for run this macro.

As I got error "Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)':
Syntax error in From clause.
[Updating MS - Access fields through MS-Excel cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764560/updating-ms-access-fields-through-ms-excel-cells)

kindly guide.......

Comment: This is an SQL problem. Please post the SQL statement that you used.

Answer (score 0):

To use ADO stuff you have to add the below to your references:
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Object Library

As for the syntax error, perhaps pasting some code and telling us which line the debugger says is erroring out on would help. My initial guess is some sort of select statement that is selecting something that doesn't exist -- but without code/intent/example data it would be hard to pinpoint.

Comment: The referenced article uses late binding, so it is not necessary to add a reference to the library. Furthermore, syntax error in from clause, is a purely sql problem, so posting the sql statement should be sufficient.